# Delete item from many to many collection in EF 6 without loading data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I using entity framework 6 and I have one question. Exist some option to delete an item from many-to-many collection without loading data? I have tried some tips, that I have found here on stackoverflow, but nothings works with EF 6 (i have tried attach, disable lazy load and entity framework plus library).

For example I have models (code first):

```
public class Book
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Book> Books{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I can add and remove items:

```
var book = dbContext.Books.Find(1);
var actionCategory = dbContext.Categories.Find(5);

book.Categories.Add(actionCategory); // or book.Categories.Remove(actionCategory);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Problem is, that book.Categories items are loaded from database because lazy loading. In this part of code I don't need loading any data, I need only add or remove one item. Only DELETE or INSERT sql query without any SELECT.

Exist any options in EF 6 how I can insert or delete one item in collection without loading all related data?

Thanks for help and any usefull example.

Comment: Entity Framework is currently using a hidden mapping table `BookCategories` (or something along those lines). To delete entries from this table, you'll need to make an entity type to access it directly on the context instead of through navigation properties. If this is an exception to your general usage, it would be simpler to just execute a stored procedure.

Comment: This doesn't work, because if I make a new entity BookCategories and run add-migration command, then EF create a new table BookCategories and the original many-to-many table renamed to BookCategories1. I tried it and this is result. Two tables.

Comment: An update: Attach() is working for Add() method, I can do this:
`var category = new Category { ID = 1 };`
`dbContext.Category.Attach(category);`
`book.Categories.Add(category);`
`dbContext.SaveChanges();`

But for Remove() method I can't use Attach()..it doesn't working.